# When I set a function to run onselectedindexchanged, my program just ignores the command

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I'm making a webpage. The goal here is to have a file open when you select it from a dropdown list. Here's the trouble code I have right now:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownFiles" runat="server" Height="18px" onselectedindexchanged="File_Opener" Width="380px">
                <asp:ListItem>Please choose a file...</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

See that "onselectedindexchanged" part? Well in the codebehind, I have the following function:

```
public void File_Opener(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here's where I would open the files, but it never even hits this function!
    }
```

For some reason, selecting something in the dropdown list never even triggers that function. plsexplain.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set the dropdown to autopostback.

Comment: Weird. When I do that, it just duplicates everything in the list! Any other ideas?

Comment: what do you mean it duplicates the list? As in you see more copies of the same list items and you still do not get a hit in your handler? If your handler is still not being called try adding a 'handles dropdownFiles.selectedindexchanged' after the function declaration or use add handler to bind the event.

Comment: Exactly; it makes a copy of everything in the original list and then adds it to the list again. What library is that command in? VS doesn't recognize anything like it.

Comment: I am not sure why the list is duplicating, that is strange. As for addhandler here is the msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899(v=vs.95).aspx. I forgot myself for a moment when I suggested to add the 'handles' verbiage since you are using C#.

Comment: Whoops! I accidentally had it loading everything in to the dropdown every time I loaded the page. When it was re-loaded, it would just append the list, rather than creating a new one. Anyways, fixed that pretty easily. Now on to the real problem!

Comment: were you able to add a handler? I think there is a disconnect between where you declare the tag and where the event is being bound. Also it is odd that the drop down would get a second list though instead of the page being reloaded. Is this in an updatepanel or something?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad user experience to have a file open or take an action on a selection, why??? Because I might think I'm selecting a file name and click the wrong one. It's better to have a button to launch whatever process you want to do after the file is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AutoPostBack` property:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownFiles" runat="server" Height="18px" onselectedindexchanged="File_Opener" Width="380px" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Please choose a file...</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Humor me:  try using the proper casing on `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.  See if that makes a difference.